# Yii2, группировка вывода ListView

Tags: php, yii2

Добрый день! Есть виджет ListView с помощью которого я вывожу записи - новости сайта.

```
<?php
    use app\models\News;
    use yii\widgets\ListView;
    use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Story::find(),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    echo ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '_list',
        'summary' => false
    ]);
    ?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то группировать вывод записей в ListView, например по дню публикации, т.е. идёт дата, затем посты за эту дату, новая дата и соответственно посты уже за другую дату.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так (отсортировав данные по дате):

```
'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget)
{
    static $prevDate = null;
    $result = $this->render('_list',
        ['model'=>$model, 'printDate' => $prevDate != $model->date])
    $prevDate = $model->date;
    return $result;
}
```

_list.php:

```
if ($printDate)
{
    echo '<div class="clearfix">';
    echo \Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->date);
    echo '</div>';
}
```